# How do you store your swift API data?

Tags: swift

I am trying to store the token into a data model that I have set up.

I am very new to this, and so far if I print() I can see that I have the values, however they are not being stored in my Data().token.

```
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

class MyRequestController {

    func getToken() {
        
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "URL")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("Basic AUTH", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("AWSALB=efzS5NSzJXZ4OpGhrFJLjdemrPBlAW5H36T6T5AVneKb+5F9PGVi1VMmBpGe8SKom145AhE2MM6vZAvLGFVQezt2qG6hC8a12mshJewTwJYJFq9YCDfkK49kRhdE; AWSALBCORS=efzS5NSzJXZ4OpGhrFJLjdemrPBlAW5H36T6T5AVneKb+5F9PGVi1VMmBpGe8SKom145AhE2MM6vZAvLGFVQezt2qG6hC8a12mshJewTwJYJFq9YCDfkK49kRhdE", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] data, response, error in
          guard let data = data else {
            print(String(describing: error))
            semaphore.signal()
            return
          }
          semaphore.signal()
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(TokenInfo.self, from: data)
                Data().token = jsonData.token
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait()
    }
    
    struct TokenInfo: Decodable {
        let token: String
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't included your `Data` object here (by the way, naming something `Data` is going to lead to some confusion since there's already something named that in Swift), but you are creating a *new instance* of it when you do `Data()`, so it's unclear where you're trying to read this information. As of yet, the question doesn't deal with SwiftUI at all -- this is just Swift. If you're trying to use it in SwiftUI, it seems likely you'd want `MyRequestController` to be a `ObservableObject` with a `@Published` property to hold the data. Also, you don't need the semaphore here.

Comment: I created a Data modal and named it Data. ive been using it every file, if i do a print(Data().name) it ill give me the information saved in that data model... i guess i dont know what you mean.

Comment: So it is supposed to be a singleton? If you include the relevant code, it'll be easier to diagnose this issue.

Comment: Note, you can easily rename your `Data` to `DataModel` or whatever, in Xcode using right mouse click on your 
`Data` class -> Refactor->Rename, so easy. P.S. why are you using the `DispatchSemaphore`?

Comment: I changed it to DataModel but it is still not storing past the view. 

I also removed DispatchSemaphore. I had it there because that’s what postman did lol.